# php-cuong customer avatar

Tags: magento2, customer

I just installed [php-cuong customer avatar](https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-customer-avatar) on magento 2.1.8.

My problem is that when I want to upload an image in customer panel it has error and not to upload image. In admin panel, customer tab when I choose a customer and upload image it saves in pub/media but not show avatar and sends error.

Comment: Hello @pegah, any solution worked for you ?

Comment: No, i just tried myself and create another module

Comment: Great, I have also created a module for customer Avatar

Comment: Sounds nice! could you please share it with me?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Its well known M2 Bug/Issues.

Its fixed in develop branch,

For work around you can modify below file to make it work.

> module-customer/Model/FileUploader.php

Around line **113**

Replace below :

```
 $result['tmp_name'] = $result['path'] . '/' . ltrim($result['file'], '/');
```

Replace with :

```
$result['tmp_name'] = ltrim($result['file'], '/');
```

Clear cache and Try to upload an image from admin.

It should work.

Comment: if it resolve your issue, Than accept answer to help other community.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response, but not work for me, could you please install the module? if it is possible for you

Comment: What do you mean by install module ?

Comment: (https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-customer-avatar) install it please, you can see whats wrong with him, as i said above, it doesnt save image from customer panel

Comment: @pegah, You have issues from frontend OR backend ?!!

Above you mention that you have issues from admin image upload. ??

Comment: dear lazy coder, after installation of this module, in customer panel (front-end login) when i want to upload an avatar it will not upload. also in admin panel (customer section) when i want to upload an avatar, it goes into pub/media but doesn't show in front-end.

Comment: Well its extension issue, you can contact author of this extension.